# Does there exist an infinite set S that is closed under infinite unions but not finite unions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does there exist an infinite set $S$ of sets, such that for every infinite subset $I$ of $S$, $\bigcup I \in S$, but $S$ is not closed under finite unions?

Comment: $S=\{X\subseteq\mathbb N:|X|\ne2\}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$S=\{\,A\subseteq \Bbb N\mid 1\in A\,\}\cup \{\{2\},\{3\}\}.$$
Then $\{2\}\cup\{3\}\notin S$, but every infinite union will contain $1$ and be $\in S$.