# Is there an uncountable set of sets that is closed under finite union and uncountable union, but not under countably infinite union?

Tags: set-theory

Does there exist an uncountable set $S$ of sets such that it is closed under finite union and uncountable union, but not always closed under countably infinite union?

Comment: If you allow (arbitrary) repetitions in the union, then every countably infinite union can be written as an uncountable union. Do you completely forbid repetitions, or allow some repetitions, or all?

Comment: How about the family of open sets? $U_x=(-x,x) , 0\lt x\le 1$

Comment: I don't allow repetitions. It has to be distinct.

Comment: $\{ \alpha \in \operatorname{On} : \alpha < \omega \lor \omega_1 < \alpha \leqslant \omega_2\}$

Comment: @DanielFischer You should post your answer as a comment, along with the proof that that set has the properties that I am looking for.

Comment: [This is getting **quite annoying**.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695129/does-there-exist-an-infinite-set-s-that-is-closed-under-infinite-unions-but-not) PLEASE consider adding context from previous questions that prompted you to ask your question, even more so in the case that these are *your* questions and you asked them somewhat recently.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I apologize. I wasn't aware that it was impolite. I will be better in the future.

Comment: Thank you. It's not the first time you were asked to do that, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such sets exist. An example is
$$S = \{ \alpha \in \operatorname{On} : \alpha < \omega \lor \omega_1 < \alpha \leqslant \omega_2\}\,.$$

First we show that $S$ is not closed under countable unions:
$$\omega = \bigcup_{\substack{\alpha \in S \\ \alpha < \omega}} \alpha \notin S\,,$$
and there are countably many finite ordinals.

$S$ is closed under finite unions, since $S$ is totally ordered by inclusion, hence the union of a finite subset of $S$ is the largest of these elements of $S$.

And $S$ is also closed under uncountable unions, since every uncountable subset $T$ of $S$ contains an uncountable ordinal, say $\beta$, whence
$$\omega_2 = \bigcup S \geqslant\bigcup T = \sup T \geqslant \beta > \omega_1$$
shows that the union belongs to $S$.